# Python pptx: Why is my chart frame empty even though I followed the docs exactly?

Tags: python, charts, powerpoint

pptx - Chart is not appearing on the slide. Followed docs exactly and nothing is showing, there is a defined chart area showing but it is an empty frame on the slide containing no data. Here is the code with some dummy values. The actual values will be lifted from an excel sheet with openpyxl. All the imports are for the wider code but ive listed them all incase im missing one or theres conflicts etc.  All caps variables are global measurements defined at the top of my code, all using Inches() so wasnt relevant to paste *everything* in.

```
from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.dml.color import ColorFormat, RGBColor
from pptx.util import Inches, Pt
from pptx.enum.shapes import MSO_SHAPE
from pptx.enum.text import PP_ALIGN
from pptx.chart.data import CategoryChartData
from pptx.enum.chart import XL_CHART_TYPE
from openpyxl import load_workbook

prs = Presentation("templatetheme.pptx")
prs.slide_height = SLIDEH
prs.slide_width = SLIDEW

blank_slide = prs.slide_layouts[BLANKLAYOUT]
slide = prs.slides.add_slide(blank_slide)
shapes = slide.shapes   

chart_data = CategoryChartData()
chart_data.categories = ["DQ", "Grant", "Set", "Ref", "V", "Wit"]
chart_data.add_series = ("Decisions", (50, 50, 50, 100, 150, 75))
    
slide.shapes.add_chart(XL_CHART_TYPE.COLUMN_CLUSTERED, CHARTXPOS, CHARTYPOS, CHARTX, CHARTY, chart_data)
```

I expect to initialise the CatChartData(), add the x axis category labels, then add a single series of values to it and add the chart to the right hand side of my slide.

What actually happens is I only get a blank frame with no data showing. The frame is in the dimensions and the size I specify so i know the arguments have reached the add_chart method, just no data.

Comment: Just to clarify, ive tried slide.shapes AND just shapes since shapes is already defined as slide.shapes